# Use OpenStreetMap in Basemapgallery - Manually

Tags: openstreetmap, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online-basemaps

I don't know how to add the OpenStreetMap to the basemapgallery. I want to do this manually because when I use ShowARCGIS basemaps:true I get too many base maps that I don't use.

Here's my code:

```
function createBasemapGallery() {
//add the basemap gallery, in this case we'll display maps from ArcGIS.com including Bing maps
        var basemapGallery = new esri.dijit.BasemapGallery({
        showArcGISBasemaps: false,
        bingMapsKey: 'BingKey',
         map: map  }, "basemapGallery");

    var basemapRoad = new esri.dijit.Basemap({ layers: [new esri.dijit.BasemapLayer({ type: "BingMapsRoad" })], id: "bmRoad", title: "Bing Maps Wegen", thumbnailUrl:"images/basemap_streets.jpg"

    });
 basemapGallery.add(basemapRoad); 

var basemapAerial = new esri.dijit.Basemap({ layers: [new esri.dijit.BasemapLayer({ type: "BingMapsAerial" })], id: "bmAerial", title: "Bing Maps Luchtbeelden", thumbnailUrl:"images/basemap_imagery.jpg"

    }); 
basemapGallery.add(basemapAerial);

 var basemapHybrid = new esri.dijit.Basemap({ layers: [new esri.dijit.BasemapLayer({ type: "BingMapsHybrid" })], id: "bmHybrid", title: "Bing Maps Hybride", thumbnailUrl:"images/basemap_imagery_with_labels.png"

    });

 basemapGallery.add(basemapHybrid);



    var layer5 = new esri.dijit.BasemapLayer({ url:"http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer" }); var basemap5 = new esri.dijit.Basemap({ layers:[layer5], title:"Lichtgrijs Canvas", thumbnailUrl:"images/light_gray.png" });
 basemapGallery.add(basemap5);

    var layer6 = new esri.dijit.BasemapLayer({ url:"http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer" }); var basemap6 = new esri.dijit.Basemap({ layers:[layer6], title:"Topografisch", thumbnailUrl:"images/basemap_topographic.jpg" });
 basemapGallery.add(basemap6);

    basemapGallery.startup();


    dojo.connect(basemapGallery, "onError", function(msg) {alert(msg)});

    }
```

Comment: Better like this?

Comment: This (http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/map_openstreetmap.html) might useful..I am researching on your question..

Comment: I saw that one yes, but how do i do that as a basemap.

Comment: According to my knowledge..you have to insert your layers in above code..Its already the OSM base map.Try to add sample layer then check.At my end the display is blank & I think OSM service is not working.

Comment: Already found it in the API Reference

Answer (score 3):

Found it out in the API Reference:

http://help.arcgis.com/EN/WEBAPI/JAVASCRIPT/ARCGIS/help/jsapi_start.htm#jsapi/basemaplayer.htm

```
var openstreetmap = new esri.dijit.Basemap({
      layers: [new esri.dijit.BasemapLayer({
        type: "OpenStreetMap"
      })],
      id: "OpenStreetmap",
      title: "Open Street Map",
        thumbnailUrl:"images/OpenStreetMap.png"

    });
    basemapGallery.add(openstreetmap);
```

Thanks for helping